# Is it safe to use laptop on a shipping box like this?

Tags: laptop

Is it safe to use laptop on a shipping box like this?

[image]

Comment: Duct tape around all 12 edges so as to give it strength and it should be decent.

Answer (score 0):

Henry, as John said duct taping the edges around the box is a great idea to give it strength.  You shouldn't have any thermal issues when the laptop gets warm, just ensure you have adequate venting, and a flat surface.  It beats using your lap and a blanket!

Comment: I would suggest having vents at the bottom or raising the lappy to increase airflow. Mostly as safety measures.

Comment: @Alrl I agree, the intake vents I think are on the bottom, so using a small book or something sturdy to put under the top left, and top right corner to raise the laptop slightly off the box to allow sufficient airflow.  I would just be sure you don't cover the intake.

Answer (score 0):

Safe, most likely but probably not a good idea if you are running CPU intensive tasks that may cause it to run very hot. Cardboard is made of layers with air-gaps, so it is a good insulator which is the opposite you want for dissipating heat.

There are purposely built stands to lift a laptop up. Generally, those either have a gap and hold the laptop on two sides or are made of a solid mesh. Some models even have a fan that is powered by a USB port of the laptop. Those mesh laptop support with fan also really work.

If cost is an issue, it is easy to improvise something that will help. If you have 4 rubber erasers, just place one below each corner of the laptop. This is saved one Dell laptop here that always overheated on any flat surface. Basically, anything that can allow airflow will help. Erasers also are non-slip, so will prevent the laptop moving around on the cardboard.